# Java - Variable used in class constructor not being used

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a connect-4 game and this is the class that is supposed to keep track of whose turn it is.

turnIdentify.java

```
public class turnIdentify{
public turnIdentify(){
    int turn = 0;
}

//prints whose turn it is to move, then increments the turn.
private void sayTurn(int a){
    if(a == 0 || a%2 == 0){
        System.out.print("It is X's Turn.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("It is O's Turn.");
    turnIncrement(a);
}}
//increments turn by 1+b
private void turnIncrement(int b){
    turn = b+1;
}}
```

What I plan to do is to call sayTurn(turn); in the main file to print whose turn it is to play, and by doing so call turnIncrement(Turn) to increase the turn. That way, when sayTurn is called during the text turn, the value for the turn will have already been incremented. The problem is that the int turn declared in the constructor is not being recognized as the same turn under turnIncrement. Eclipse says "turn cannot be resolved to a variable." How can I make sure that turnIncrement changes the actual turn, not some temporary instance of it? Also, why isn't it recognizing the variable turn?

Comment: I suggest you learn about variable scope. You need to declare a field variable here rather than a local variable.

Comment: Also a good idea to use a Boolean if you are only use it to distinguish turn.